# JS - assign a passed function to a global object

Tags: javascript, function

I need to assign a passed function to a global object.

```
var globalObj = {};

function assignFunc(pFunc){
    globalObj.func = pFunc;
}

assignFunc(function(){});
globalObj; // globalObj == {}
```

And even if it were not an anonymous function,

```
function sampleFunc(){};
assignFunc(sampleFunc);
globalObj; // globalObj == {}
```

If i try assigning an anonymous passed function to the window object,

```
function assignFunc_2(pFunc){
    window.someFuncName = pFunc;
    globalObj.func = window.someFuncName;
}

assignFunc_2(function(){});

window.someFuncName; // function
globalObj; // globalObj == {}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/banL9fxp/

Comment: BTW using global variables isn't a good idea...

Comment: Works fine for me in chrome

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, your first code block works just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/banL9fxp/3/ and perhaps more clearly: https://jsfiddle.net/banL9fxp/4/

Comment: Invoking the function directly on globalObj works...verify it with a function body that uses alert or something; JSON.stringify does not print functions.

Comment: please test it on IE11. - it just isn't working

Comment: yes work fine with me too, in chrome u pass `assignFunc_2(function(){console.log(' call assignFunc_2')}); `

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8fczno2b/ -- worked for me in IE 11.0.38

Answer (score 0):

Your code works just fine. I'd assume that this is just your browser console hiding the property from you.

```js
var globalObj = {};

function assignFunc(pFunc) {
  globalObj.func = pFunc;
}

assignFunc(function() {});
console.log(typeof globalObj.func); // "function"
```